# How to add multiple product without refreshing page in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am creating campaign.
 In that campaign i want to add multiple products without refreshing page and store the detail of that products in database.

[image]

ProductCatalogController :

```
public function storeProduct(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, $this->rules);

        $input=Input::all();
        var_dump($input);
        exit();
        $campaign_product=ProductCatalog::create($input);
        return redirect('product_catalog');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add ajax like this

```
var myKeyVals = { A1984 : 1, A9873 : 5, A1674 : 2, A8724 : 1, A3574 : 3, A1165 : 5 }

var saveData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "urlToMethod",
      data: myKeyVals,
      success: function(resultData){
         alert("Save Complete") }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, AJAX to call the function without refreshing the page.

you can learn about ajax in this tutorial.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: i also know ajax to call the function without refreshing the page. but i don't know how to add multiple product .. if u know than answer me..

Comment: you can do it in multiple ways. 1) take a javascript array and do add delete of products in that array and when the person clicks next send the request to the server. 2)  whenever a person clicks add send the data to the server using ajax and add it to your database. 3)Add this data to the session.